# javascript. passing a variable to a variable input field

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

I have a price calculator with multiple input fields but the calculation remains the same. What I have is this:

```
function calcone() {
    calc(Number(document.calc.priceboxa.value),
         Number(document.calc.amountboxa.value),
         document.calc.answera.value,);
}

function calctwo() {
    calc(Number(document.calc.priceboxb.value),
         Number(document.calc.amountboxb.value),
         document.calc.answerb.value,);
}

function calc(price, amount, costbox) {
    var one = price / amount,
    costbox = one;
}
```

I can't get "costbox = one;" to send the variable back to the answer* fields. What am I doing wrong? I've searched and can't find an answer to this.

New code that works:

```
function calcone() {
    calc(Number(document.calc.priceboxa.value),
         Number(document.calc.amountboxa.value),
         document.calc.answera,);
}

function calctwo() {
    calc(Number(document.calc.priceboxb.value),
         Number(document.calc.amountboxb.value),
         document.calc.answerb,);
}

function calc(price, amount, costbox) {
    var one = price / amount,
    costbox.value = one;
}
```

Comment: Pass the element rather than value of an element to function and set value within function. Pass document.calc.answera & document.calc.answer. And set costbox.value = one;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `document.calc.answerb.value` into your function as `costbox` it's like writing an address on a piece of paper and saying `costbox` will know where to find `document.calc.answerb.value`

So when you do:

```
costbox = one;
```

All you've done is rewritten the address on that sheet of paper. You haven't changed the value of `document.calc.answerb.value` which costbox used to point to; instead, you just told costbox to point to something else.

So what you have to do is actually change what `costbox` is **pointing** to...not the costbox itself. The question now is how do you resolve this? The answer is that instead of changing the value of costbox, you change the properties of costbox.

This means that instead of passing in

```
document.calc.answerb.value
```

you pass in

```
document.calc.answerb
```

and do `costbox.value = one`

```
function calc(price, amount, costbox) {
    var one = price / amount,
    costbox.value = one;
}
```

Now instead of wiping that piece of paper clear of the address and writing down a new one, you're visiting the address and saying: "I want the value changed"

Answer (score -1):

Your passing the value to the method not the element you need to do this:

```
function calcone() {
    calc(Number(document.calc.priceboxa.value), Number(document.calc.amountboxa.value));
}

function calc(price, amount) {
    var one = price / amount;
    document.calc.answera.value = one;
}
```

Or:

```
function calcone() {
    calc(Number(document.calc.priceboxa.value), Number(document.calc.amountboxa.value), document.calc.answera);
}

function calc(price, amount, answerbox) {
    var one = price / amount;
    answerbox.value = one;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote the correct answer atleast say why please otherwise there is no point to the downvote...

Comment: Why would you downvote a correct answer and no "no reason" is not a good enough reason.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted. Your second code works and that is what the first person said to do.